# Prevent HAProxy from toggling back from fallback to master

Tags: haproxy, high-availability

We have Redis master-slave setup, and we want to fallback to the slave once the master failed. But if it has failed it should never toggle back, even if the master is online again.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a workaround to do what you need. Simply put a very high value on the `rise` parameter, and an `inter` of a few seconds, like the example below:

```
listen  sql-cluster 0.0.0.0:1433
        balance roundrobin
        server  sql01 192.168.100.109:1433 check backup
        server  sql02 192.168.100.180:1433 check inter 5s fall 3 rise 99999999
```

In this example, `sql01` is `backup`, and `sql02` is active. If master is down, `sql01` is up. For `sql02` to return to active, it must do 99.999.999 healthy checks, with interval of 5 seconds... this is around 15 years!

Answer (score 7):

Use the `stick`  option. From the [official HAproxy blog](http://blog.haproxy.com/2014/01/17/emulating-activepassing-application-clustering-with-haproxy/):

> Automatic failover without failback
>
> The configuration below makes HAProxy to use s1 when available, otherwise fail over to s2 if available.
>   When a failover has occurred, no failback will be processed automatically, thanks to the stick table:

```
backend bk_app
 stick-table type ip size 1 nopurge peers LB
 stick on dst
 server s1 10.0.0.1:80 check
 server s2 10.0.0.2:80 check backup
```